# Getting objectManager / serviceLocator in fieldset in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2, service-locator

In order to get my object manager inside my fieldset's init() function I followed the [docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html#the-specific-case-of-initializers)
At first I found out that I had to change

```
public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocator $sl)
```

to

```
public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $sl)
```

otherwise I got an error:

```
setServiceLocator() must be compatible with that of Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface::setServiceLocator()
```

When calling `$this->getServiceLocator()` I get an instance of the FormManager.
Additionally calling `$this->getServiceLocator()->getServiceLocator()` returns `NULL`.

Since I am still new to DI I wonder if I am missing a place to inject?

Testing I switched from

```
$form = new MyForm();
```

to

```
$formManager = $this->serviceLocator->get('FormElementManager');
$form        = $formManager->get('Application\Form\MyForm');
```

Since then I get this error:

```
exception 'Zend\Di\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Invalid instantiator of type "NULL" for "Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface".'
An abstract factory could not create an instance of applicationformmyform(alias: Application\Form\MyForm).
```

Anyway reading some other threads using the `ServiceLocator` Awareness isn't recommended. Is using the `FormElementProviderInterface` the alternative?

I used the ServiceLocatorAwareInterface before in my classes like this:

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class MyClass implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    protected $services;

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->services = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->services;
    }
```

and simply calling it per service locator in my c

```
$sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
$myClass = $sm->get('Application\Service\MyClass');
```

without having to set an DI. Is this necessary for Fieldsets / Form and where / how exactely?

I tried to inject my Form and Fieldset this way:

```
    'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Application\Form\CreateCostcenter' => function (\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface $sl) {
            $form = new \Application\Form\CreateCostcenter();
            $form->setServiceLocator($sl);
            return $form;
        },
        'Application\Form\CostcenterFieldset' => function (\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface $sl) {
            $fieldset = new \Application\Form\CostcenterFieldset();
            $fieldset->setServiceLocator($sl);
            return $fieldset;
        },
    ),
),
```

The injection works for my form when calling it in my controller:

```
$form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Form\CreateCostcenter');
```

But of course it won't pass the serviceManager to the Fieldset.

Anyway I don't understand why there has to be a config for the serviceManagerAwareness since it works with other class by just implementing it.
There also is no hint in the docs for advanced usage since **ZF 2.1**:

[use an initializer (like Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface) to inject a specific object to all your forms/fieldsets/elements](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html#the-specific-case-of-initializers)

Comment: Have you actually added an entry in your servicemanager config for the form? or your DI definitions?

Comment: Please see me edited post for this Andrew, thanks!

Comment: have you configured the DI as so: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.di.configuration.html

Comment: Can you please check my updated post, @Andrew? As mentioned I see documentation for the DI / ServiceLocatorAwareness in the docs.